# how to disable Accelerated Networking on Azure VM

Tags: azure, networking, virtual-machine

i have enabled Accelerated Networking on Azure  Vm..now i want to disable accelerating networking but unable to find a way. since i want to change the size of vm and accelerating network is preventing to change the size.

please suggest

Comment: Out of interest, why did you want to disable Accelerated Networking, and what VM size where you on?

Comment: @pnizzle he seems to have answered this in the question - he apparently wanted to resize down to a size that didn't support accelerated networking (maybe something with only one vCPU for example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use azure powershell to do it.

```
Remove-AzureRmAcceleratedNIC -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName> -VMName <VMName> -OsType <OsType>
```

You need to download the script file in this [link](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/EnableDisable-Accelerated-6d14b027#content), then refer to the usage below.

[image]

For more details, refer to this [link](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/EnableDisable-Accelerated-6d14b027#content).

Comment: thanxx for the solution,
it will work definately ,but it will remove or recreate the IP address ,which i dont want as its configured in many places ,is there any other solution for this ??

Comment: @RohitChouhan I am not sure, currently could not find other way via official docs.

Comment: i also searched alot about the same but cudnt found ant solution to this.

Comment: @RohitChouhan May be you could post the idea in the [azure vm feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/216843-virtual-machines).

Answer (score 8):

This is a setting on the network interface. For a single machine you could try running this command from the cloud shell on the azure portal:

```
az network nic update --accelerated-networking false --name <network interface name> --resource-group <resource group name>
```

Recommend typing this command out not copy pasting from this page to avoid hyphen hell. Case sensitive so all lower case.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/nic?view=azure-cli-latest#az-network-nic-update

Comment: Works like a charm. Just make sure to select the correct subscription before running it. To select the subscription 'az account set --subscription <subcription name>'

Comment: Worked perfectly. BTW I did not need to set the subscription.

Answer (score 3):

For VMSS ([Virtual Machine Scale Sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/overview)), the process is a bit less straight forward, but still possible.

Say your resource group is `RG001` and the VMSS name is `VMSS001`, then you can issue

```
az vmss update -g RG001 -n VMSS001 --set virtualMachineProfile.networkProfile.networkInterfaceConfigurations[0].enableAcceleratedNetworking=false
```

Answer (score 1):

I added a new NIC from the VM networking tab and it seems that accelerated networking is disabled by default. Then I detach the previous NIC (with accelerated networking) and was able to resize my VM.

Comment: yaah this will work...but i was looking for something that wont let change the NIC.